# p:outputPanel does not render page sections

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two `p:ouputPanels` which have the `rendered` attribute. They should be rendered when the value of the underlying `getter/setter` changes. However, the underlying values change in the right order. The first panel disappears, However the second panel does not show up. Even NOT in the HTML code!

My two panels:

```
    <p:outputPanel id="PanelParent">

     <h:form>
        <p:outputPanel id="PanelForm" rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityForm()}">

        <h:commandButton value="Button"
                                            action="#{PageService.persist}"
                                            styleClass="btn btn-primary opal_btn submit_form_new" />
     </h:form>                      
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel id="PanelMessage" rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityMessage()}">

        //Message

        </p:outputPanel>

    </p:outputPanel>
```

I appreciate your answer!!!

**-UPDATE-**

In the code, I reference to the persist method and in this method I change the getter and setter of the visibility for each section.

**-UPDATE1-**

OK here is in fact my code:

```
            <p:outputPanel id="parentPanel">
                <p:outputPanel id="PanelForm"
                    rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityForm()}">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h:form class="homepage_invitee_form" action="" method="POST">

                                <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"
                                    closable="true" />

                                <h:inputText required="true"
                                    value="#{PageService.instance.name}"
                                    name="name" placeholder="Last Name"
                                    styleClass="lastname_new" id="lastname_new"
                                    type="text placeholder" />

                                <h:commandButton value="Press"
                                    action="#{PageService.persist()}"/>

                                    <f:ajax render="" />
                                </h:commandButton>

                            </h:form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </p:outputPanel>

                <p:outputPanel id="PanelThank"
                    rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityThank()}">
                    <div>
                        Message
                    </div>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:outputPanel>
```

I really do not see where it fails? ;(

Comment: How are you calling them

Comment: @Andy what do you mean? In the code through the el expression: `rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityForm()}`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear enough. How is the condition evaluated ? Are you clicking a button ? How are you updating the page once the condition is evaluated

Comment: I published an answer based in some assumptions. You should rewrite your code (close tags properly) and publish also what are you doing to update your client part.

Comment: @Andy the condition is evaluated through the getter and setter. When i click on a button this condition is set...

Comment: ok, can you post just a little bit more code please.

Comment: One last thing, are these panels inside or outside a form. Just trying to create a sample on my end to see if I can duplicate.

Comment: Maximus, I think it would be better if you post more code, like the entire form and some of the relevant backing bean method because I tried this and it works. When the page loads button shows up. When you click it //Message appears.

Comment: Oh quick question. Are you setting `VisibilityMessage` to true in your `persist` method.

Comment: @Andy I updated my code. And YES I set the visibility in my `persist` method

Comment: Not `VisibilityForm` but `VisibilityMessage`. Let me know. I'll look again.

Comment: also, take out `action` and `method` in `<h:form>`, this is not needed.

Comment: yep, I also update this variable in my persist method and also proved the logs!

Comment: Ok, well I'm able to reproduce it on my end. Give me a sec.

Comment: `visibilityForm` in order of `isVisibilityForm`. Getters do not need `get`/`is` preffix

Comment: Ok, Maximus do you want the answer or should I refactor your code also ?

Comment: @Andy please write it as an answer, and also post the code, so that I can except it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like Xtreme Biker said `<f:ajax>` `render` attribute will render elements that are already present in the DOM. In your case, `<p:outputPanel id="PanelThank">` `render` attribute was evaluating to `false` so it was not in the DOM. Therefore, `<f:ajax>` could not render it. You need to point to something that is always visible. Change

```
<f:ajax render="" />
```

to

```
<f:ajax render=":PanelThank" />
```

but more importantly change

```
<p:outputPanel id="PanelThank" rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityThank()}">
    <div>
        Message
    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

to

```
<p:outputPanel id="PanelThank">
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityThank()}">
        <div>
            Message
        </div>
    </p:outputPanel>           
</p:outputPanel>
```

Consider refactoring your code also. For instance, `action` and `method` in `<h:form>` is not needed.

Comment: ok, thx for your answer! However, now I am at the point where I get an exception from my persist method: `serverError: class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`. When I remove the nested `ajax` in `the commandButton` everything works fine...

Comment: @maximus Try this `<f:ajax execute ="@form" render=":PanelThank" />` and let me know how it turns out. Be sure to put a value in the `inputText`. I don't really know what your `persist` is doing so I can't give you a concrete answer. I can show you what I did to test it if you want. I was using simple booleans and not JPA but honestly I think you should ask a new question (not that I mind helping you here now, I don't) but you could give more people a chance to see your problem and help you understand better (maybe something is messing up between the ajax request and the `JPA`).

Comment: yes, cause you are the best answerer, for the jpa problem I will set up a new question. Thx for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

`rendered` attribute [defines if JSF will render your component in the DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264118/1199132). Your problem is you cannot update a component which is not in the tree because you simply don't have it:

```
<p:outputPanel id="PanelForm" rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityForm()}">
    //my Form
<p:outputPanel>

<!--Fails if not PageService.isVisibilityForm(), because you don't have the component itself in the tree! So can't find it-->
<p:ajax update="PanelForm"/>
```

Your best is to wrap your content in another container which is always rendered and update it instead of the other one:

```
<h:panelGroup id="updatablePanel">
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{PageService.isVisibilityForm()}">
        //my Form
    <p:outputPanel>
</h:panelGroup>

<p:ajax update="updatablePanel"/>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I did it as you explained it in your answer, however, I get `<p:ajax> Event attribute could not be determined: null` In which container do I have to give the `p:ajax` ?

Comment: Which component are you using to update your view? You mention it is one of your buttons.. You have to wrap the ajax tag inside your component. You can use `f:ajax` too. Look at the [Ajax 'Hello World' Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/).

Comment: I want to let disappear the `PanelForm` and to let appear the `PanelMessage`. Therefore I update the two components. Do I have to put in each of these two panels an `ajax` component? I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: You're welcome, try just `<f:ajax render="@form"/>` into your button. That'll make the whole form to be rendered again. By the way, fix your code again plz.

Comment: I don't think ajax is the problem. True it's more efficient but since he's submitting the entire form it should still work and it is on my end (at least the code given).