# JSF selectOneMenu value changed event triggering help (Java Server Faces)

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, events, selectonemenu

I want to trigger an Ajax event when the selected value of the selectOneMenu is changed.

The idea is to update the textArea based on the new value.

```
    <h:form id="selectForm">
        <h:graphicImage id="carImage">
        </h:graphicImage>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="carList" value="#{RequestBean.index}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{CarInfoBean.allCarNames}" itemLabel="#{CarInfoBean.carNumber}" />
            <f:ajax  render="carDescription"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <br/>

        <h:inputTextarea id="carDescription" value="#{RequestBean.infoString}" readonly="true" >
        </h:inputTextarea>
    </h:form>
```

The part I am confused on is how I trigger the event. Do I need a valueChangeListener in the  select tag? Do I set something for the change attribute of the selectOneMenu, or can I specify the triggering event within the ajax tag somehow?

Thanks,
Sam French

Answer (score 1):

An [ajax-Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkace.html#gkhzs) should do the thing:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    ...
     <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"  listener="#{CarInfoBean.foo()}" render="carDescription" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

(Note: you have to use the *update* attribute, since the *render* attribute does [something different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263714/jsf-rendered-attribute).)

Comment: Ok, do you mean f:ajax? I don't see any update attribute in the documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkabr.html#gkafn

Comment: Or in the documentation for java 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-ajax003.htm#GKABR

Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, I used primefaces and confused the tags here … http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyAction.jsf I'm updating the code.