# How to denied/allow a menuitem to a specific user in java / jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Good Day Everybody,

I am developing a web application, using JSF and primefaces, in one of my views I have a primefaces element which is a Slide Menu with Menu Items like this.

```
<p:slideMenu style="width:140px">
<p:menuitem value="My products" url="products.xhtml"/>
<p:menuitem value="products" url="home.xhtml"/> 
<p:menuitem value="Delete Users" action="#{menuView.delete}"/>
<p:menuitem value="Sale" url="save.xhtml" />
<p:menuitem value="Log Out" action="#{login.logout()}"/>
 </p:slideMenu>
```

I have a derby DB with some users on it, I'm not trying to create Roles or something, I just would like to know if there's a way I can block/gray out the menu item "Delete Users" to the rest of users except the user admin in my db.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSF: rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263714/jsf-rendered-attribute)

Comment: Or maybe the disabled attribute?